# How to shorten links in my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress

I need to shorten all links in my site into (ka.sa)

How can I do that?

Comment: Nice, good luck! ... Seriously though, if you want our help, 1. post your relevant code, What have you tried thus far? show us that and show effort in your question: http://stackoverflow.com/tour please take the tour

Comment: There are no code, i need to look the way to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Plugin like [Shortnit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortnit/screenshots/) that shorten the urls

Comment: Hi, i try this, but not work withe me, my original domain is (kam.com) and we need to short it to (ka.co)